# Why sudo su don't pass as root, but password is ok?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

In Ubuntu I have one normal user root1. And till now when I want to be a root I do:

```
root1@host:/home/root1$ sudo su
[ sudo ] password for roo1:
```

type password
and I had:

```
root@host:/root:#
```

but now I type a password and get

```
root1@host:/home/root1$
```

but without info about wrong password or any clue. If I put wrong password I obviously get info about that.

So What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

when you use "sudo", you must type the user password (and not the root password)

And you need add this user in the sudoers list (execute visudo or edit /etc/sudoers)